# What this kind of timeline chart is called?

Tags: time-series, visualization

I created this [timeline chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CMW0.png) myself because I couldn't find a library that implemented a similar kind of chart (I checked Plotly and Seaborn). I'm interested in finding out what other people call it. Is it unusual to see charts like this? The idea for this chart came from a [similar one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlfKH.jpg) I saw in the Apple Watch app.

| Custom timeline chart made by me | The one from Apple Watch app |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Some kind of timeline chart] | [image: Similar chart from the Apple Watch app] |

Comment: It is a type of 2d timeline heatmap showing seasonality/periodicity/daily cycle on the vertical, and the long term time series on the horizontal.  Your chart  interleaves two of them by day.  https://humansofdata.atlan.com/2016/11/visualizing-time-series-data/ or https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/02/visualization-in-time-series-using-heatmaps-in-python/ does it as a heatmap.